# How can I setup webpack to minify and combine scss and javascript like CodeKit?

Tags: coffeescript, sass, npm, webpack

I'm having trouble using webpack instead of [Codekit](https://incident57.com/codekit/) v1.9.3. I started working to move from CodeKit to Grunt and Gulp, and then learned about `webpack` which sounds very cool. I just can't seem to get it working correctly.

### "Like Codekit" means I can:

- Write `javascript` with the `coffeescript` syntax
- Have all script source files and libraries minified / uglified and combined into one file
- Selectively include components of the `bootstrap-sass` (scss) framework as needed
- Maintain a small file with bootstrap customizations via sass variables, like `$brand-primary`
- Use `webpack --watch` to compile both scripts and styles automatically when they are changed
- End up with one css file and one script file that can be included with a stylesheet and script tag.

---

### Codekit Project Setup

***Bower resources:***

I'm currently storing these globally, outside of the project:

```
~/bower_components/twbs-bootstrap-sass/vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

Because CodeKit supports compass, I've got this in my `config.rb` file:

```
add_import_path "~/bower_components/twbs-bootstrap-sass/vendor/assets/stylesheets"
```

***Project Structure***

```
js/fancybox.js
js/main.js               <-- currently the compiled js 'output' file
js/main.coffee

css/styles.css           <-- currently the compiled css 'output' file

scss/styles.scss
scss/modules/_bootstrap-customizations.scss
scss/modules/_typography.scss
scss/partials/_header.scss
scss/partials/_footer.scss
```

***Contents of styles.scss***

```
@import "modules/bootstrap-customizations";  # local customizations
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
...                                          # load bootstrap files as required
@import "bootstrap/wells";
```

---

### System Setup:

- system: OS X 10.9
- node - v0.10.32
- npm - v2.1.7
- zsh - zsh 5.0.7 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)

node was installed with homebrew's `brew install node` and seems to be working fine otherwise.

---

### What I've Tried

I've read over these pages:

- http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
- https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto
- http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/bootstrap-sass-webpack

I've attempted to create a `webpack.config.js` file several times, my latest attempt was several versions of this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
    "./node_modules/bootstrap-sass-webpack!./bootstrap-sass.config.js",
    "./js/main.coffee"
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    }
};
```

***Webpack Error***

When I run `webpack` I get this:

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-sass-webpack/~/css-loader!/Users/cwd/~/sass-loader!./~/bootstrap-sass-webpack/bootstrap-sass-styles.loader.js!./bootstrap-sass.config.js
stdin:1: file to import not found or unreadable: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables
```

***NPM Error***

I get an error when attempting to `npm install bootstrap-sass`, and not had any luck when searching for a solution. I'm not even sure I need this module.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "bootstrap-sass"
npm ERR! node v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.7
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package bootstrap-sass does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer bootstrap-sass-webpack@0.0.3 wants bootstrap-sass@~3.2.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/cwd/webpack-test/npm-debug.log
```

---

### Sources of Confusion

The most confusing parts of webpack for me are:

1. Where should things like `require("bootstrap-sass-webpack")` be added - is it in the `webpack.config.js` file, or in the `js/main.js` file?
2. Should modules like this available to webpack as soon as they are installed with `npm install` ?
3. I thought that I should do `npm install webpack -g` so that webpack was installed globally, and use `npm install` without the `-g` for the other modules. However, I don't see any `node_modules` folder being created in my project. Shouldn't there be one?
4. How are the search paths determined / specified for things like `require("bootstrap-sass-webpack")` ?

What node modules should I install to be able to do this? And what should my `webpack.config.js` look like?

Comment: I have a very similar configuration, I'm using exlir which is based on top of gulp, but it calls the webpack loading mechanism. I cannot get bootstrap-sass-webpack to write any asset files, beyond show they are called "file.css", "file.wof" when they are bundled together. Nothing writes to disk.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

### Introduction

Webpack is mainly a JavaScript-bundler. Its "native" language is JavaScript and every other source requires a loader which transforms it to JavaScript. If you `require()` an html-file for example...

```
var template = require("./some-template.html");
```

...you'll need the [html-loader](https://www.npmjs.org/package/html-loader). It turns...

```
<div>
    <img src="./assets/img.png">
</div>
```

...into...

```
module.exports = "<div>\n    <img src=\"" + require("./assets/img.png") + "\">\n</div>";
```

If a loader doesn't return JavaScript, it needs to be "piped" to another loader.

---

### How to load SASS-files

#### Configure loaders

In order to use SASS you'll need at least the [sass-loader](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sass-loader) and the [css-loader](https://www.npmjs.org/package/css-loader). The css-loader returns a JavaScript string. If you want to import the returned JavaScript string as [StyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet), you'll also need the [style-loader](https://www.npmjs.org/package/style-loader).

Run `npm i sass-loader css-loader style-loader --save`

Now you need to apply these loaders on all files that match `/\.scss$/`:

```
// webpack.config.js
...
module: {
    loaders: [
        // the loaders will be applied from right to left
        { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style!css!sass" }
    ]
}
...
```

You can also pass options to [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) as query parameters:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style!css!sass?includePaths[]=" + 
        path.resolve(__dirname, "./bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/"
}
```

Since bootstrap references icons via the `url()` statement, the css-loader will try to include these assets into the bundle and will throw an exception otherwise. That's why you'll also need the [file-loader](https://www.npmjs.org/package/file-loader):

```
// webpack.config.js
...
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style!css!sass" },
        { test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$/, loader: "file" },
    ]
}
...
```

#### Configure entry

To include bootstrap into your bundle there are several ways. One is via the multi-entry option as you've already tried. I recommend to use **a single entry** where you `require()` your main sass-file:

```
// main.js
require("./main.scss");
```

Given that your `includePaths` are configured then you can do:

```
// main.scss
// Set the font path so that url() points to the actual file
$icon-font-path: "../../../fonts/bootstrap";

@import "bootstrap";
```

Please note that import statements inside scss-files are not touched by webpack because libsass has no api ([yet](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/21)) to provide custom resolvers.

To prevent code duplication it's also important to have a **single** main sass-file, because webpack compiles every sass-file individually.

With the coffee-loader installed via npm your final `webpack.config.js` should look like:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./js/main.coffee",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style!css!sass" },
            { test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$/, loader: "file" },
            { test: /\.coffee$/, loader: "coffee" }
        ]
    }
};
```

---

### Webpack globally?

It's best **not** to install webpack globally, because it's a dependency of your project and thus should be controlled via npm. You can use the [scripts](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html)-section of your `package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack --config path/to/webpack.config.js & node server.js"
    }
}
```

Then you just need to run `npm start`

Comment: really appreciate you taking the time to answer this one.

Comment: Based on the premises that webpack is "mainly a JavaScript-bundle", I am wondering if we are asking webpack to do too much on the CSS side of thing that it feel awkward. Would you think using Webpack for purely JavaScript ES6 workflow and using Gulp for autoprefixer+SASS workflow a better combination or do you think we should absolutely try to gun for one build-tool approach?

Comment: I understand your concerns, but one benefit I see is, that webpack is also handling url() statements in CSS files. It makes totally sense to me to treat CSS just as another module. I've written "mainly a JavaScript-bundler" because JS is the universal language that can host HTML, CSS, Markdown, whatever as strings.

Comment: So, there is no way of building css without `require`ing some file somewhere? Should I stick with gulp/grunt/whatever for building css?

Comment: how to add hot reloading with sass ?

Comment: @Sahan You should ask a separate question.  But if you do some searches, you'll find articles that refer to including the Sass/SCSS directly in the JavaScript files, via `require()`

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. One comment I'd like to add is that I had to add the trailing slash when setting the `$icon-font-path` variable.