# requirejs not loading the object properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs, cornerstone

I am configuring angularjs project dependecies using `requirejs`

following are the configurations

```
"cornerstone-core":"emp/cornerstone.min",
"cornerstone-math":"emp/cornerstoneMath.min",
"hammer":"emp/hammer.min",
"properties":"emp/properties"
"clientParameters":"emp/clientParameters"
"cornerstone":"emp/cornerstone"
"cornerstoneMath":"emp/cornerstoneMath"
"cornerstoneTools":"emp/cornerstoneTools"
"cornerstoneWADOImageLoaderCodecs":"emp/cornerstoneWADOImageLoaderCodecs"
"cornerstoneWADOImageWebWorker":"emp/cornerstoneWADOImageWebWorker"
"myApp":"emp/myApp"
```

Runtime dependencies are,

```
clientParameters : [ "properties" ],
cornerstoneMath : [ "properties", "clientParameters", "cornerstone-core", "cornerstone-math", "hammerjs" ]
cornerstone : [ "properties", "clientParameters", "cornerstone-core", "cornerstone-math", "hammerjs" ],
cornerstoneTools : [ "properties", "clientParameters", "cornerstone-core", "cornerstone-math", "hammerjs" ],
myApp : [ "properties", "clientParameters", "cornerstone", "cornerstoneMath", "cornerstone-core", "cornerstone-math", "hammerjs" ]
```

In cornerstone.js I am loading the modules in a following way,

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
  if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
    module.exports = factory();
  else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define("cornerstone", [], factory); // error line
  else if(typeof exports === 'object')
    exports["cornerstone"] = factory(); 
  else
    root["cornerstone"] = factory();
})(this, function() {
return (function(modules) {
```

I am getting the following error,
     `myApp.js:2312 Uncaught(in promise) ReferenceError: cornerstone is not defined`

at line `define("cornerstone", [], factory);` 
 when I am replacing the error line with `root["cornerstone"] = factory();` everything is working fine.

**[EDIT]**
factory method is bootstrapper used in this question: [Trying to understand Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776061/trying-to-understand-webpack)

Comment: Can you show us your factory function?
 `define("cornerstone", [], factory);` cannot throw `ReferenceError: cornerstone is not defined`. It looks one of your modules is depending on a global variable called `cornerstone`, which is not present when a module loader is used.

Comment: cornerstone variable is part of cornerstone.js and everything is working fine when I am using `root["cornerstone"]=factory()`

Comment: Can you show me the 2312nd line if myApp.js?

Comment: Updated the question. it is not breaking in myApp.js, it is breaking in cornerstone.js while accessing the cornerstone object

Comment: I did check cornerstone.js, it's distribution version doesn't reference itself (https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone/blob/master/dist/cornerstone.js) That still means you have some code referencing cornerstone without importing it properly

Comment: So to be clear: the line `define("cornerstone", [], factory)` cannot throw the error `Uncaught(in promise) ReferenceError: cornerstone is not defined`, because it is not referencing `cornerstone` at all. We will have to look into the `factory` function, and walk down the stacktrace a littlebit.

Comment: Can you paste full error object?

Comment: @TamasHegedus you are right, it is breaking in one of my file i.e `myApp.js` at `image =  cornerstone.renderGrayscaleImage;` In chrome Dev I have added a watch on `cornerstone` variable and its state is `undefined`

Comment: Have you tried adding `var cornerstone = require('cornerstone');` somewhere in `myApp.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using modules, first you have to import `corerstone`. With AMD modules it would look something like:

```
define(["angular", "cornerstone"], function (angular, cornerstone) {
    ....
});
```