# With Webpack, is it possible to generate CSS only, excluding the output.js?

Tags: css, node.js, npm, bundling-and-minification, webpack

I'm using [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) with the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

In my project, I have some build scripts. One of the build scripts is supposed to bundle and minify CSS only. As I'm using Webpack for the other scripts, I found it a good idea to use Webpack even when **I only want to bundle and minify CSS**.

It's working fine, except that I can't get rid of the `output.js` file. I don't want the resulting webpack output file. I just want the CSS for this particular script.

Is there a way to get rid of the resulting JS? If not, do you suggest any other tool specific for handling CSS? Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## There is an easy way, no extra tool is required.

There is an easy way and you don't need extra libraries except which you are already using: [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) with the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

### In short:

**Make the output js and css file have identical name, then the css file will override js file.**

### A real example (webpack 2.x):

```
import path from 'path'
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'

const config = {
  target: 'web',
  entry: {
    'one': './src/one.css',
    'two': './src/two.css'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist/'),
    filename: '[name].css' // output js file name is identical to css file name
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css') // css file will override generated js file
  ]
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is not possible when using mini-css-extract-plugin. Is there any alternative for mini-css-extract-plugin?

Comment: mini-css-extract-plugin works fine for me, as documented at https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#extracts-css-into-separate-files and https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-css/

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, that is currently not possible by design. webpack started as a JavaScript bundler which is capable of handling other "web modules", such as CSS and HTML. JavaScript is chosen as base language, [because it can host all the other languages simply as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26876311/1343851). The extract-text-webpack-plugin is just extracting these strings as standalone file (thus the name).

You're probably better off with [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) which provides various plugins to post-process CSS effectively.

Comment: Given this is not the selected answer, can somone confirm that this response is not true?

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to execute webpack with the Node API and control the output with the [memory-fs](https://github.com/webpack/memory-fs) option. Just tell it to ignore the resulting js-file. Set the output.path to "/" in webpackConfig.

```
var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
var mfs = new MemoryFS();
compiler.outputFileSystem = mfs;
compiler.run(function(err, stats) {
    if(stats.hasErrors()) { throw(stats.toString()); }
    mfs.readdirSync("/").forEach(function (f) {
        if(f === ("app.js")) { return; } // ignore js-file
        fs.writeFileSync(destination + f, mfs.readFileSync("/" + f));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can clean up your `dist` folder for any unwanted assets after the `done` is triggered.  This can be easily achieved with the [event-hooks-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-hooks-webpack-plugin)

```
//
plugins: [
        new EventHooksPlugin({
            'done': () => {
                // delete unwanted assets 
            }
        })
    ]
```

Good Luck...