# Pack HTML with html-webpack-plugin without packing any JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

In another question, [an accepted answer with 11 upvotes suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46875379/607407) using webpack's `html-webpack-plugin` to merge HTML+JS+CSS.

Not a single word on how though, so that's my question. I have a documentation file, in HTML. It includes two external CSS files and one javascript file (syntax highlighter). I would like to bundle it all into one HTML file for easy distribution.

I tried to use webpack without packing any JS with following `webpack.config.js`:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Documentation',
            template: "index.html",
            filename: 'index_bundle.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

But that caused an error because webpack requires input and output script path:

```
Error: 'output.filename' is required, either in config file or as --output-filename
```

So how do I do this. Is webpack even the right choice?

Comment: When you say merge, do you expect javascript and css line of codes to be injected into the html file? If so, I think that's not what html-webpack-plugin does, it merely put a script / link tag pointing to the generated css/js. If this is all you need webpack to do, it's probably the wrong tool

Comment: @DerekNguyen Yeah, well that's exactly what the linked question asked, and webpack is the accepted answer, so I kinda went from there.

Answer (score 0):

What's tricky here is that webpack and `HtmlWebpackPlugin` each have their own entry-output pipeline. You don't care about webpack's entry point and output; you care about `HtmlWebpackPlugin`'s, but in order for `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to run at all, you have to let webpack do its thing.

There's a clever trick that I stole from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43556756/152891 that you could do here -- tell webpack to output its bundle at index.html, and then tell `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to output to the same location. Webpack will run first, and then `HtmlWebpackPlugin` will overwrite its output. You still need to define an entry point for webpack, but this can be a blank index.js.

```
webpack.config.js:

const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: './src/index.js', // Default value, can omit
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html', // Default value, can omit
      inject: false,
      minify: false
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "index.html",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

You can either keep a blank `./src/index.js` file in your repo, or you could define a little inline plugin in your `webpack.config.js` to create the file on run, and add it to your `.gitignore`.

```
  plugins: [
    {
      apply: (compiler) => {
        compiler.hooks.beforeRun.tap('NoOpPlugin', () => {
          fs.writeFileSync('./src/index.js');
        });
      }
    }
  ]
```