# How to load CSS files with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

Im trying to have my CSS file in the src folder copied into the dist folder on build - Im currently using a HTML file in my dist - ie im not using a javascript file so dont want the styles to be created as javascript.I just need the files to be copied into the dist. Heres my current config that isnt working.

```
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = {
    devServer:{
      port:8000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: 'html-loader',
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/i,
              use: [ 'style-loader','css-loader'],
            },
            {
              test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|glb|gltf|typeface.json)$/i,
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                  publicPath: './',
                  name: '[name].[ext]'
              },
          },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

I then use a link tag to add the css into the index.html file eg

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
```

But this just adds javascript to the HTML file it builds in the dist.

How can i do this?

***EDIT: Im trying to add CSS files without merging them into my Javascript files

Comment: You need to use style-loader and css-loader as a module

Comment: I am using both of those - Check my post

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question. Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237119/pack-html-with-html-webpack-plugin-without-packing-any-javascript

Comment: This seems to be regarding HTML rather than CSS. Maybe my question wasnt worded properly

Comment: https://youtu.be/eddzBlXBl3Y at the end of this video Brad extracts css files from the bundle. Sorry, I am outside and don’t have time to write it here as an answer

Comment: Thanks man! Looks good

Comment: No problem :) happy to help

Comment: options: {
          modules: true, try this

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/). As written in the documentation:

> This plugin extracts CSS into separate files. It creates a CSS file per JS file which contains CSS. It supports On-Demand-Loading of CSS and SourceMaps.

To use it, you can first install it, import it, add a loader and a plugin to your webpack config. Here's an example (don't forget to note the order must be correct):

```
...
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
      ...
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    ...
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

It will also add an automatic link tag to your css files in index.html results.